# LED bulb won’t work in a standard outside porch light fixture

Tags: lighting

I can’t get LEDs to work together in twin wired Port Charlotte lights. I can put in an incandescent light with an LED bulb and just the led works. I put both LEDs in and neither works. I put both incandescent lights in and they both work. Power shows present on voltage meter. Could it be the switch? I have a standard light switch from 50 years ago technology

Comment: Are the LED bulbs of the same brand?

Comment: What does "twin wired Port Charlotte lights" mean? Is "Port Charlotte" a brand or a style or a location? What is "twin wired"? Maybe include a picture, too.

Comment: Is this a dusk to dawn controlled fixture? Or an electronic switch ?

Comment: *Power shows present on voltage meter.* What voltage are you reading at either socket with the meter?

Comment: Try a small value (25, 40  watt) incandescent, and a large-value (75, 100W) incandescent as the two bulbs.  Is the small-value one brighter? That would indicate series wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Given the symptoms, I have to suspect that this fixture is wired with the bulbs in series, rather than with the bulbs in parallel.

So, two incandescents - operate happily if somewhat dim and yellow on half-voltage. Bulbs would last a long time and veer towards "bug light" yellow without the ugly yellow paintjob, so it's not unreasonable for a "porch light" fixture.

One LED one incandescent - adequate voltage for the LED, so little current you don't even notice the glow on the incandescent.

Two LEDs - half voltage, ain't nobody happy.

Diagnostic - one bulb, one empty socket - what happens?

Comment: I've never seen that in a fixture. Would you assume that it's a manufacturing flaw?

Comment: Not necessarily. Could have been designed that way, with the long life and bug-lite/cheerful yellow intent; could have (depending on fixture design) been field-wired that way (which could mean it's correctable for "not 60 volt" LEDs to work in it.)